# What to type in my terminal so that my Javascript express can connect to localhost:3000, and print out the middleware on terminal console?

Tags: javascript, express, terminal, localhost, middleware

I am new to javascript so I want to learn what to type on terminal so that my JavaScript express can connect to localhost:3000 and print the middleware that it is supposed to print ('Server started; type CTRL+C to shut down ').

```
app.listen(3000);
console.log('Server started; type CTRL+C to shut down ');
```

I somehow figured out what to type on command line, and have been printing it out until my terminal suddenly quit itself and I can't remember how I did it in the first place. I tried retrieving the past commands I have typed, but it seems like the session itself was completely lost.
On terminal, I am now typing

```
node [filename.js]
```

which shows me that it is working, but doesn't print out the middleware (which is, 'Server started; type CTRL+C to shut down ').

EDIT: Someone already suggested to look through terminal history and I have - shows me every command I entered except the ones from last night.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to look back at your terminal history to retrieve the command that was working previously.

```
history
```

Comment: It does not show me the commands that I entered yesterday. It only shows the command from today and the day before yesterday, so I think that yesterday's session is lost.

Answer (score 0):

After writing the code on [whateverFile.js], you must also have a file called app.js.
I was trying to enter the command

```
node whateverFile.js
```

You should instead type

```
node app.js
```

and will get the result on terminal.